# Integrate getstream activity feed in flutter

Tags: flutter, getstream-io

So I am trying to integrate activity feed feature from get stream into flutter. But I am not able to get the docs for that. My question is, is it possible to integrate feed feature to flutter app ?

There are various tutorials for integrating chat feature but not the feed feature. Please help.

Note: I am not an experienced flutter developer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no Flutter SDK or customized docs for Flutter at the moment but we're considering to allocate some resources for it in Q3 this year.

Comment: So you mean currently I cannot integrate feed in flutter app (using the rest api or any other mean) ?

Comment: Definitely you can with REST api. I would suggest following side by side with another SDK (in which you're comfortable) and its docs are here: https://getstream.io/docs_rest/

Comment: Thanks mate finally got the answer

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest you to use [Flutter platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels). I had to do that for a project I am working on currently. If you have any questions feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated Dart package to interact with the API: https://pub.dev/packages/stream_feed

And a core package that simplifies the low-level client by managing state and providing builders: https://pub.dev/packages/stream_feed_flutter_core

Tutorial: https://getstream.io/activity-feeds/sdk/flutter/tutorial/